# Concatenating strings in C# object structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object structure that looks like this:

```
var Results = new List<ResultObj>()
    {
        new ResultObj()
        {
            Messages = new List<MessageObj>()
            {
                new MessageObj()
                {
                    Message = "message 1"
                },
                new MessageObj()
                {
                    Message = "message 2"
                }
            }
        },
        new ResultObj()
        {
            Messages = new List<MessageObj>()
            {
                new MessageObj()
                {
                    Message = "message 3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I use LINQ or another C# approach to get a single string with all the Message values concatenated together? Something like what's below

"message 1, message 2, message 3"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String.Join` and `SelectMany`:

```
String.Join(", ", Results.SelectMany(x=> x.Messages).Select(y => y.Message ));
```

Comment: The use of `SelectMany(x => x)` will select the `ResultObj` items, not the `Messages` that belong to each `ResultObj`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Enumerable.SelectMany` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten the list, then use the [`String.Join` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx).

```
var query = Results.SelectMany(r => r.Messages)
                   .Select(m => m.Message);
var result = String.Join(", ", query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allStrings = results.SelectMany(r => r.Messages).Select(m => m.Message);
var joined = String.Join(", ", allStrings);
```