# How to join array of structs over a field

Tags: c#

I have an array of type T. T has a string field. I would like to join the array of T's based on the field.

e.g.,

```
struct T
{
   string name;
}
List<T> Ts;
...
String.Join(", ", Ts);
```

But that basically prints out T, T, T, T... Since it join the T's ToString value. While I could override ToString, I'm more interested in doing it properly and efficiently.

Thanks

Comment: *While I could override ToString, I'm more interested in doing it properly and efficiently.* What makes you think `ToString` is not an efficient solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242836/concatenating-strings-in-c-sharp-object-structure

Answer (score 1):

you can use LINQ `Select` like this:

```
string.Join(", ", Ts.Select(x => x.name))
```